# gettings started with language.ext (functional C#)

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn more about functional programming, using the language.ext (C#) library as a starting point.  I am trying to use an Either monad, but there is something I am missing.  See for a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dates
{
    public class AssignmentDate
    {

        public static Either<string, AssignmentDate> Create(DateTime date)
        {
            if (date < MinValue)
                return Left<string, AssignmentDate>("date out of range");

            return Right<string, AssignmentDate>(date);
        }

        public static DateTime MinValue => new DateTime(1950, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

The types Left<> and Right<> cannot resolve.  I am obviously missing something, but what?  Am I using Either<> correctly?  Is this the correct way to return when using Either<>? Can anyone point to more examples of language.ext?  Many thanks for any help provided.

Comment: You need to import the containing namespace and use `new Left<...>` and new Right<...>`.

Comment: thanks for answering Lee - normally Visual Studio is good enough to find this, but looking through the LanguageExt.Core package, I cannot find Left<> nor Right<> (which I expected to find in the same namespace as Either<>).  It makes me think I have misunderstood something fundamental here - hence the question.

Comment: I found what I was missing - "using static LanguageExt.Prelude;" This resolved things correctly. Strange that Visual Studio behaves differently for this (and that I couldn't find anything via the Object Browser).  Thanks for your help Lee.

Answer (score 6):

I'm the author of Language-Ext.  `Left` and `Right` are constructor functions, rather than types in their own right, they both construct an `Either<L, R>`.  Many of the types have constructor functions in the static class `Prelude`, that's why you need to do `using static` on it.  It's not a namespace but a class.

You could have written:  `Prelude.Left<L, R>(...)` and `Prelude.Right<L, R>(...)`.

This is to simulate algebraic data types (ADTs) in functional languages like F# where `Either` could be defined like so:

```
type Either<'l, 'r> =
  | Left of l
  | Right of r
```

Which would allow you to construct an `Either` like so: `Right(x)`.

Other constructor functions are: `Some(x)` and `None` for `Option`, `List(x,y,z)` for `Lst`,  `Set(x,y,x)` for `Set`, etc.

The `Prelude` class makes it easy to include a ton of base functionality with one `using static`, rather than having to do `using static LanguageExt.Either`, `using static LanguageExt.Option`, etc.

By the way, a more functional way to write your example would be:

```
public static Either<string, AssignmentDate> Create(DateTime date) =>
    date < MinValue
        ? Left<string, AssignmentDate>("date out of range")
        : Right<string, AssignmentDate>(date);
```

The reason is that the ternary operator is an expression, whereas you were using multiple statements to get the result.  If you're learning functional programming  you should always try to work with expressions wherever you can.  The exception is where you need to declare local variables, but mostly you can wring pure expressions in C#.  If your expressions get too big, break them down into smaller functions.  One side-effect of functional programming is that your functions will get smaller and smaller; sometimes only single line affairs.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to write an answer.  I really appreciate it.  I have been flirting with trying to learn functional programming for a little while now, and my question is in part the result of trying to take what I am reading in "Functional Programming in C#" and convert it to the expectations of the library that you have made. It also doesn't help that I'm usually trying to do this at 11:30pm... ultimately this is something I would like to be able to apply at work, but it looks like I have a long way to go yet.

Comment: It takes a bit of time to get into the functional mindset for sure.  You'll have a series of aha moments where stuff falls into place.   I'm a reformed OO programmer too and the process for me has been enlightening.

Comment: Next on the agenda is to figure out smart constructors and validation.  I am hoping to build this into a proof of concept, combining functional with domain driven design concepts.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing - "using static LanguageExt.Prelude;" Not sure why, but Visual Studio treated this a bit differently, and I couldn't find any reference to Left nor Right in the Object Browser.